# ABP audit log truncate and replace data with three dots

Tags: database, truncate, abp, audit-trail

Recently I'm using ASP Boiler Plate for my project. I found that the audit log was created automatically after the API function ended. However, the audit value inserted into the db was truncated and replaced with three dots.

I've gone through a lot of forum but there isn't any solution found.
Is there any setting that we can make to change the behavior of replacing the data with three dots?

example as below:-

```
{"input":{"id":12345,"modificationDT":"2022-08-15T10:00:00.000000+08:00","isChangesMade":false,"details":{"status":13,"emailSentDT":"2021-05-0T00:00:00","emailSentId":12,"msgSentDT":"ASAP","remark":null,"itemsRepresentativeId":15,"itemsRepresentativeName":"xxxxxx"},"itemsChosen":[{"id":527,"itemDescription":"xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx ","isItemInUse":true,"itemPrice":13.2,"itemQuantity":25,"remarks":null}],"return":[{"itemId":595,"itemCategory":"11","itemReturnRemarks":"","isItemBroken":false,"returningPolicyAcceptanceStatus":true,"isCompensationNeeded":false,"compensationMethod":0,"adminRemarksOnItem":"","CompensationAmount":0.0,"userUpdate":true,"itemImage":[{"compensationId":900,"itemImageURL":"https://ksuHVUJH-jnsadkna.KBidbwJBK!@.OLjba7s87/HBBDA/hbjdas-!#!!@#!j-jb3123-31231knc^&kn/jkkdwqjbdkjq(-60.jpg","imageId":109231}],"imageCreationDT":"2021-01-01T15:29:23.728136","itemModifiedDT":"2021-05-05T10:10:10.120912+08:00","UserAcceptanceId":"JDSAJBD-FKAJBFKB-FKQJFBKBWF-KSJABKFBAS-XXXX","adminId":89182},{"itemId":907,"itemCategory":"21","itemReturnRemarks":"XXXXXX","isItemBroken":true,"returningPolicyAcceptanceStatus":true,"isCompensationNeeded":true,"compensationMethod":3,...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase `AuditLogActionConsts.MaxParametersLength` in the `PreConfigureServices` method of your module.

The default values from [AuditLogActionConsts.cs](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/312995263abf918fe7e0ac6734066217cf885494/modules/audit-logging/src/Volo.Abp.AuditLogging.Domain.Shared/Volo/Abp/AuditLogging/AuditLogActionConsts.cs) are:

```cs
public static int MaxServiceNameLength { get; set; } = 256;
public static int MaxMethodNameLength { get; set; } = 128;
public static int MaxParametersLength { get; set; } = 2000;
```

Comment: I don't have ```AuditLogActionConsts.cs``` file.

Comment: `using Volo.Abp.AuditLogging;`

Comment: thanks to your help, I've found the solution.
https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=21760